# linux touch files with matching date

Tags: linux, sed

I have a bunch of folders with many sets of files with matching file names and different extensions, eg

```
foo.a
foo.b
foo.c
bar.a
bar.b
bar.c
baz.a
baz.b
baz.c
```

The files with .a extension have the correct date, but I need to set the modified date of the other files with same filename to match. I can list all the files with the .a extension and trim it like so

```
find -name '*.a'| sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
```

and I know it will involve "touch --reference" but that's as far as I've got. Help?

Comment: What is *a correct modification date*?

Comment: You want each set of `name.*` files to have the same modification dates? Specifically the date of the `name.a` file?

Comment: Entirely unreliable (depends on file collation order to sort the `.a`/desired file first) but `for file in *.a; do touch -r "${f%.a}"*; done`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for f in *.a; do touch -r "$f" "${f%.a}".*; done
```

How it works:

- `for f in *.a; do`

  This loops over all files with the `.a` extension
- `touch -r "$f" "${f%.a}".*`

  Using `f` as the reference file, this changes the dates of all other files in the directory that differ only in extension.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Is it reliably safe to operate on the same file as both reference and argument?

Comment: @EtanReisner Works for me.  `touch` gets the date from the reference file and then changes all the files that you list to match.   Changing the `.a` file to match itself is redundant but causes no harm.

Comment: Assuming that's guaranteed behaviour, sure. It doesn't need to be (especially in terms of access time and large argument lists/slow disk). I grant that avoiding this makes for more complicated solutions.

Comment: out of curiosity, why does "${f%.a}" amount to name where f = name.a?

Comment: @UStralian `${f%.a}` is an example of the shell feature to remove a suffix.  In general, `${parameter%word}` will remove suffix `word` from the value of `parameter`.  This and many other useful features are explained under _parameter expansion_ in `man bash`.